# File delete after datasnap server method call in Delphi XE6

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I have a Datasnap client server application written in Delphi XE6. I am calling a server method that creates temporary file using a TFileStream, fills it with my report in TStream format from my http post, and returns it to my client.  This all works as needed. However, at the end of the method, I call deleteFile method to delete the temp file from the server, but it never gets delete. What am I doing wrong?

```
var
  r,f: String;
  SS: TStringStream;
  Uid: TGuid;
begin
   CreateGuid(Uid);
   f:= ChangeFileExt(GuidToString(Uid),'.rpt');
   result:= TFileStream.Create(f, fmCreate or fmOpenWrite);

  r := getRunReportJSON(ARunReportObj);
  SS := TStringStream.Create(r, TEncoding.ASCII);
  try
    try      
      ServerContainer1.idHttp1.Post(gUrl, SS, result);
      Result.Position:= 0;
    except
    end;
  finally
    SS.Free;
    if FileExists(f) then
      DeleteFile(f)
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As David said, you can't delete the file until the `TFileStream` is destroyed first so it can close its handle to the file.  If you want the file to auto-delete when the server is done using it, you can either:

1. open the file with the Win32 `CreateFile()` function directly so you can specify the `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` flag, and then wrap the resulting handle with the `THandleStream` class.

   ```
   type
     TMyHandleStream = class(THandleStream)
     public
       destructor Destroy; override;
     end;

   destructor TMyHandleStream.Destroy;
   begin
     inherited;
     CloseHandle(Handle);
   end;

   var
     h: THandle;
     r, f: String;
     SS: TStringStream;
     Uid: TGuid;
   begin
     CreateGuid(Uid);
     f := 'C:\some folder\' + GuidToString(Uid) + '.rpt';
     h := Windows.CreateFile(PChar(f), GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE, 0);
     if h = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then RaiseLastOSError;
     Result := TMyHandleStream.Create(h);
     try
       r := getRunReportJSON(ARunReportObj);
       SS := TStringStream.Create(r, TEncoding.ASCII);
       try
         ServerContainer1.IdHTTP1.Post(gUrl, SS, Result);
       finally
         SS.Free;
       end;
       Result.Position := 0;
     except
       Result.Free;
       raise;
     end;
   end;
   ```
2. derive a new class from `TFileStream` and override its destructor to delete the file:

   ```
   type
     TMyFileStream = class(TFileStream)
     public
       destructor Destroy; override;
     end;

   destructor TMyFileStream.Destroy;
   begin
     inherited;
     DeleteFile(Self.FileName);
   end;
   ```

   ```
   var
     r, f: String;
     SS: TStringStream;
     Uid: TGuid;
   begin
     CreateGuid(Uid);
     f := 'C:\some folder\' + GuidToString(Uid) + '.rpt';
     Result := TMyFileStream.Create(f, fmCreate or fmOpenReadWrite);
     try
       r := getRunReportJSON(ARunReportObj);
       SS := TStringStream.Create(r, TEncoding.ASCII);
       try
         ServerContainer1.IdHTTP1.Post(gUrl, SS, Result);
       finally
         SS.Free;
       end;
       Result.Position := 0;
     except
       Result.Free;
       raise;
     end;
   end;
   ```
3. Use the `TFileStreamEx` class shown in [this forum answer](http://narkive.com/QXuEnciB.3):

   ```
   type
     TFileStreamEx = class(THandleStream)
     public
       constructor Create(const FileName: string; Mode: Word; flags: DWORD = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL);
       destructor Destroy; override;
     end;

   constructor TFileStreamEx.Create(const FileName: string; Mode: Word; flags: DWORD = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL);
   const
     AccessMode: array[0..2] of LongWord = (
       GENERIC_READ,
       GENERIC_WRITE,
       GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE);
     ShareMode: array[0..4] of LongWord = (
       0,
       0,
       FILE_SHARE_READ,
       FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
       FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE);
   begin
     if Mode = fmCreate then
     begin
       inherited Create(
         CreateFile(
           PChar(FileName),
           GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE,
           0,
           nil,
           CREATE_ALWAYS,
           flags,
           0
         )
       );
       if Handle = INVALID_HANDLE then
         raise EFCreateError.CreateFmt(SFCreateError, [FileName]);
     end
     else
     begin
       inherited Create(
         CreateFile(
           PChar(FileName),
           AccessMode[Mode and 3],
           ShareMode[(Mode and $F0) shr 4],
           nil,
           OPEN_EXISTING,
           flags,
           0
         )
       );
       if Handle = INVALID_HANDLE then
         raise EFOpenError.CreateFmt(SFOpenError, [FileName]);
     end;
   end;

   destructor TFileStreamEx.Destroy;
   begin
     if Handle <> INVALID_HANDLE then CloseHandle(Handle);
   end;
   ```

   ```
   var
     r, f: String;
     SS: TStringStream;
     Uid: TGuid;
   begin
     CreateGuid(Uid);
     f := 'C:\some folder\' + GuidToString(Uid) + '.rpt';
     Result := TFileStreamEx.Create(f, fmCreate or fmOpenReadWrite, FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE);
     try
       r := getRunReportJSON(ARunReportObj);
       SS := TStringStream.Create(r, TEncoding.ASCII);
       try
         ServerContainer1.IdHTTP1.Post(gUrl, SS, Result);
       finally
         SS.Free;
       end;
       Result.Position := 0;
     except
       Result.Free;
       raise;
     end;
   end;
   ```

Comment: Hi Remy, I tried both of your methods. The first one - I still needed to close the server app down in order for the file to be deleted. The Second one, nothing gets deleted - even if i close the server or client down.

Comment: That suggests the stream is not being freed. Did you check that?

Comment: I did, and it is being freed.

Comment: Looks like I needed to close the File Handle in your example 1:   CloseHandle(h);

Comment: @John: I fixed the handle leak.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot delete the file stream that you created until you have destroyed the file stream object. The file stream object wraps a file handle, and while the file handle exists, the file object behind it cannot be deleted.

You need to destroy the file stream object before you can delete it.

Your code has some rather odd exception handling. It swallows exceptions without discrimination in the middle of the function. Do you really want to be quite so brutal? And outside the try/except block, any exceptions will lead to the file stream object being leaked.

There's not really much point in testing whether or not the file exists before deleting it. If you succeeded in creating the file stream then you can be confident that the file exists.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the response. Since the FileStream is created in the server method and returned to the client as a TStream, is it safe to delete the FileStream in that server method?  Would you help me more to understand where i went wrong with the exception handling?

Comment: I can't really comment on what is outside of the question. I wonder why you are using a file stream at all if you only want something transient. Why not use a memory stream. As for the exception handling, why are you opting to swallow exceptions? You wrote that code. What is the reason for it? Why are you handling exceptions at all? The basic tenet here is that you should not routinely handle exceptions. Let them float up to something that knows what to do with them. Anyway, I think I explained why `DeleteFile` failed which was your question wasn't it?